# php cURL not accepting my content type

Tags: php, curl, put

I'm trying to use cURL to upload a file using PUT with a content type of application/octet-stream, but even when I set it using curl_setopt the content type is always 'text/html'. I've tested in firefox and chrome to see if it as a browser quirk or something (it wasn't) so I'm not sure what I can do about this.

```
         error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            $ch = curl_init();
            $localfile = 'upload.txt';
            $fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$localfile.'?type=file');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("content-type: application/octet-stream"));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $un.":".$pw);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            $msg = curl_exec ($ch);
            $error_no = curl_errno($ch);
            $print = curl_getinfo($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
            if ($error_no == 0) {
                    $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
            } else {
                    $error = 'File upload error.';
            }
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Try again with `Content-Type` instead of `content-type`. Maybe you need to add `Content-Length` too, I don't know if cURL will add this automatically.

Comment: @Havenard What value would I use for content length?

Comment: The exact length in bytes of the file you are trying to upload.

Comment: @Havenard I added content-length and tried the content-type capitalization, didn't work.

Comment: I suggest you try to perform this operation using a browser and then compare in the web server logs what cURL is trying to do and what the browser did after some difference. Perhaps some network debugging tool like Wireshark might help too.

Comment: I tested you code and the content-type was set correctly. Is it possible that you mistook the response header for the request header?